# adjective with from...to

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositional-phrases

I thought it was not possible to say something like the below.

> It was in the range of from (problem number)5 to (problem number)9.

Even my native friend said it sounds horribly wrong and that I should say "the range of 5 to 9". Well, it turns out he is wrong. It is possible to say "the range of from...to". http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/

So I was wondering if it would be possible to use "from...to" in some other contexts as the prepositional complement.

So would it be grammatical to say

> He was good with from (problem number) 5 to (problem number) 9 but not
>   with from 10 to 15.

I think it kind of sounds alright, and even [this nominal functions of prepositional phrases](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/nominal-functions-of-english-prepositions-and-prepositional-phrases/)
supports my claim.

But after thinking of it for too long, I'm losing it. Is it fine to say this?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples contain two prepositions in a row, which is ungrammatical. Your native-speaking friend might be referring to this issue.

> It was in the range ***of from*** 5 to 9.
>
> He was good ***with from*** 5 to 9 but not ***with from*** 10 to 15.

In the first example, you would use **of** instead of **from**. A prepositional phrase such as "in the range" requires **of**, not **from**.

In the second example, you would use **from** instead of **with**. In this case, "good" is a predicate adjective that requires **from**, not **with**.

These sentences are perfectly valid:

> It was in the range of 5 to 9.
>
> He was good from 5 to 9 but not from 10 to 15.

Comment: What do you think of 9 results that come up on COCA when I type in "range of from"? Also google search yields over 30000 results: https://www.google.com/#q=%22range+of+from%22&tbm=bks&start=80

Comment: @user3169 What do you think of 9 results that come up on COCA when I type in "range of from"? Also google search yields over 30000 results: google.com/#q=%22range+of+from%22&tbm=bks&start=80

Comment: I think if you used "range of from 5 to 10" in a sentence, your friend would say it sounds very wrong and your English teacher would mark it incorrect.

Comment: -EDIT- In the form of "He was good with (that)", you could use "He was good with (from 5 to 9 but not 10 to 15)". But don't repeat the "with from" a second time.

Comment: @whitedevil I made a mistake on my comment, so pls check it again. I was only saying leave off the second "with from" in the above "He was good with from 5 to 9 but  not .... .... 10 to 15."